# Can CockroachDB run on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cockroachdb

I am interested to test CockroachDB on a cluster of PIs. Anyone knows if this this currently possible considering they are still in Alpha?

Answer (score 6):

This may be a little late, but I recently got CockroachDB running on a Pi. The steps I had to take are available [here](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/wiki/Running%20CockroachDB%20on%20a%20Raspberry%20Pi). This is a point-in-time guide to getting Cockroach working on a raspberry pi, so the necessary steps may change in the future, and we still don't officially support ARM architectures. Please reach out on GitHub if you have any issues following the steps!

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB has so far only been tested on 64-bit x86 platforms (a note in [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) says that a 64-bit build is required). It probably won't work on the Raspberry Pi out of the box; I'm not sure what it would take to get it working there.